# linkedin companies api throws error code 500 for company without logo

Tags: linkedin-api

While getting list of companies for a user it throws 500 error code for the company which does not have a logo.

Query with logo-url param:

> curl
>   "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies:(id,name,universal-name,website-url,industries,status,blog-rss-url,logo-url,twitter-id,employee-count-range,specialties,locations,description,stock-exchange,founded-year,end-year,num-followers)?is-company-admin=true&format=json&count=1&start=2&oauth2_access_token=XXXX
>
> {   "errorCode": 0,   "message": "Internal API server error",
>   "requestId": "xyz",   "status": 500,   "timestamp": 1522908224279 }

Query without logo-url param:

> curl
>   "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies:(id,name,universal-name,website-url,industries,status,blog-rss-url,twitter-id,employee-count-range,specialties,locations,description,stock-exchange,founded-year,end-year,num-followers)?is-company-admin=true&format=json&count=1&start=2&oauth2_access_token=XXXX
>
> {   "_count": 1,   "_start": 2,   "_total": 8,   "values": [{
>       "id": 123456,
>       "name": "Cross Talk",
>       "numFollowers": 0,
>       "universalName": "cross-talk"   }] }

Can anyone help to resolve this?

Comment: I have the very same issue on the `company_search` API, I bet it has something to do with all the image url changes they've done the last few weeks.

Comment: getting the same error, with `logo_url` and `square-logo-url`

Comment: we are seeing the same issue as well. LinkedIn team, are you listening? thanks!

Comment: This appears to be new behavior -- we only noticed it in the past week or two.

Answer (score 0):

I found this as an issue from LinkedIn. This happens if the requested company doesn't have a logo. I tried adding a new logo and the API works with `logo-url` in request.